# Solr query performance with large number of docids

Tags: performance, search, solr, personalization

How would a Solr query with large number of filter queries over docids (~1000) on 1M documents perform

e.g. `q:"some query" fq:+id:("p2" OR "p3" OR "p4" OR ...)`

Is it advisible to do such a query for achieving something like a RDBMS Join. I want to filter out products in search results based on users dynamic lists (wishlist etc). Since the lists are unique for each user, it doesn't make sense to add them to the index

Answer (score 0):

Solr performs the best with the filter queries with the [Filter cache](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache).
However, I would not like to query all the ~1000 documents within a single query.
Would rather provide a pagination feature so that the results are retrieved in batches.